# How to change absolute values in list in scheme

Tags: lambda, functional-programming, scheme

I tried to change negative values in list to positive values.
But my code has some issue. :/
Please help me.
This is my code

```
(define (myabs list) 
(cond
((null? list) '())
(cons((abs (car list))(myabs (cdr list))))
))
(display (myabs '(-3 5 6 -2)))
```

but result is following as:

```
  0  (myabs (cdr list))
    At line 4 of "./main.sc"


 1  (myabs (cdr list))
    At line 4 of "./main.sc"


 2  (myabs (cdr list))
    At line 4 of "./main.sc"


 3  (myabs '(-3 5 6 -2))
    At line 8 of "./main.sc"
```

Image is following as:

This is result of online scheme compiler

Answer (score 1):

You forgot the `else` part of the last condition and have misplaced parentheses, a good IDE will help you spot these kind of errors easily (and please, indent your code correctly!) Oh, and you should *not* name any variable as "list", that clashes with a built-in procedure of the same name. This should work:

```
(define (myabs lst)
  (cond
    ((null? lst) '())
    (else (cons (abs (car lst))
                (myabs (cdr lst))))))
```

And BTW, the idiomatic way to write a solution in Scheme is to compose existing procedures, this does exactly the same and is simpler:

```
(define (myabs lst) 
  (map abs lst))
```

Comment: The second solution is definitely stronger, being much simpler and much easier to maintain. A while back I noticed that the use  of `cons`, `cdr` and `car` in someone's code, whilst not necessarily a mistake, suggests a simpler approach using `map`, `filter` or `reduce`.

Comment: Thank very much.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Oscar Lopez's answer, and this answer is more of an appendix to it.  A more general approach to the task of applying a function, `abs`, to a list is to `map` it along the list. So, we can either use the supplied `map` or as an exercise, we can create a new version of `map`:

```
; syntax (fk-map function list)

(define (fk-map f lst)
  (if (null? lst)
      '()
      (cons (f (car lst))
        (fk-map f (cdr lst)))))

; (fk-map abs '(-3 5 6 -2)) => '(3 5 6 2)
```

The new `fk-map` is recursive like a `factorial` function. The function `f` is applied in turn to the first item, and bolted onto the application of the `fk-map` on the remainder of the list. The recursion terminates when the list runs out, `(null? lst)`.

For coding Scheme, I recommend Dr Racket, which provides an easy-to-use development system:

[image: Dr Racket IDE]

Comment: very help full and kindly.  :)